# Concatenate within ActionLink with code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, concatenation, actionlink

I am trying to concatenate the `c.name` with `Response.Write(counts[c.ID]);`

Basically, in the `<li>`, I want it to be "Category name (x)".

So, basically shove the `if` statement after the `c.name`. How can this be done?

```
<li>
    <%:Html.ActionLink(c.Name, "Browse", "Listing", routes, null)%>
    <%
        if (showCounts && (bool)(ViewData["ValidCategoryCounts"] ?? true))
        {
            Response.Write("(");
            if (counts.ContainsKey(c.ID))
            {
                Response.Write(counts[c.ID]);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("0");
            }
            Response.Write(")");
        }
    %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend building the full link text within the controller code. Alternatively you could use a helper within the view markup, such as the following example:

```
<%:Html.ActionLink(Html.GetNameWithCount(c.Name, counts), "Browse", "Listing", routes, null)%>
```